# Mail_mime in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I just take over a project,and they use Mail_mime to send email.
I am using Zend to run the project and it says :
Fatal error: Class 'Mail_mime' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\dcs\config_local.php on line 76

Here is the Line 76

```
@include_once ($include_path.'\Mail.php');
@include_once ($include_path.'\Mime.php');

//$crlf = "\r\n";
$mimeparams['eol'] = "\n";
$mime = new Mail_mime($mimeparams);   // Line 76
```

Can i know how to use the same Mail_mime class in Zend ?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the class Mail_mime was not found.

Most probably this class is in $include_path.'\Mime.php' and was not correctly included.

That's why silencing errors is a bad idea. This class is required for your script to work, why would one silence errors on including the file where it resides?

If you remove @ then you might find out that those 2 files at the top were never included. I would go even further and replace include with require if your Mime_mail is really defined there.

This has nothing to do with Zend. If you wish to use Zend_Mail you can refactor your code.